# MySQL Query to get date-wise data between start date and end date

Tags: mysql, date

I have a MySQL table that contains 'startDate', 'endDate' and 'amount' to represent the amount required between start and end date.

I want to get the date-wise records for all the days in a month.

```
table:
---------------------------------------
ID | STARTDATE  | ENDDATE    | AMOUNT |
---------------------------------------
1  | 2018-01-02 | 2018-01-04 | 1000   |
2  | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-06 | 2000   |
...| ...        | ...        | ...    |
---------------------------------------
```

Required Result:

```
-------------------------
Date       | Total Amount
-------------------------
2018-01-01 | 0
2018-01-02 | 1000
2018-01-03 | 3000
2018-01-04 | 3000
2018-01-05 | 2000
2018-01-06 | 2000
2018-01-07 | 0
...        | ...
...        | ...
2018-01-31 | 0
```

The result should generate a list of dates of the current month with respective Total Amounts.

What should be the SQL query?

Comment: Your required result makes no sense.  Why do `2018-01-05` and `2018-01-06` have 2000 instead of 3000?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Pls check the data in the table: amount 1000 starts on 2018-01-02 and ends on 2018-01-04 while 2000 starts spans from 3rd to 6th. On 5th and 6th 1000 isn't added to 2000.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `GREATEST()` function for this task,

```
SELECT
    AMOUNT, 
    GREATEST( STARTDATE, ENDDATE ) as Date       
FROM
   table
ORDER BY
    Date
```

Comment: This won't give the desired results.